# How to setting up controller to return json (Laravel 5)

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

What I want to do is to return json from my controller, this is my controller:

```
class BooksController extends Controller{
    public function getIndex(){
        return View::make('books.index');
    }

    public function getBooks(){
        $books = array('Alice in Wonderland','Tom Sawyer','Gulliver\'s Travels','Dracula','Leaves of Grass');
        return Response::json($books);
    }
}
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::controller('books', 'BooksController');
```

and this is my view:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>Show Books</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" id="book-button">Load Books</a>
        <div id="book-list"></div>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#book-button').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault();
                    $('#book-list').html('loading...');

                    $.get('books/books', function(data) {var book_list = '';
                        $.each(data, function(){
                            book_list += this + '<br>';
                        })
                        $("#book-list").html(book_list);
                        $('#book-button').hide();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I load the view and I click the "Load Books" button the javascript just showing "loading...", no data from the controller is appear. what's wrong with my code?, help me guys. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

also tried to use dd($books); to see if the arry is ok and use console.log(data) to see the json

> return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);

and in js side:

data.name or data.state

remember if you are returning array in the json you need iterate id

Comment: and how if i have more than one name and state? how can i show all of them using js?

Comment: `for(var i in data)
{
     var id = data[i].id;
     var name = data[i].name;
}`